# Let be an endomorphism where is a finite dimensional inner product space If in some orthonormal basis of V mus be unitary?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $\alpha \in End(V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space.  If $||\alpha (v)|| = ||v||$ for all v in some orthonormal basis of V, must $\alpha$ be unitary? Either prove or provide a counterexample.

Comment: How about $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}$?

Comment: could you explain. all you did was copy and paste the matrix from the same exact question that was already posted on a link found on the right

Comment: please explain, thank you